# Как получить response с запущенным js ивентом

Tags: javascript, python, парсер

Написал простенький парсер, но не понимаю как достать данные из скрытой вкладки. На необходимой странице находятся 3 лота и кнопка показать еще 10, мне необходимы первые 5, следовательно как-то кнопку надо прожать. К этой кнопке привязан какой-то js ивент, который вызывает функцию function Lr(){}var Mr=null,Dr=null;. При механическом нажатии на кнопку отправляется POST запрос [image: Запрос] с полезной нагрузкой. Собственно в чем вопрос, как мне получить в каком-либо виде страницу с подгруженными лотами или же сами эти лоты. Пытался через selenium, но работает слишком медленно и криво. [image: консоль страница]

Comment: Не используйте картинки, а вставляйте текст. В крайнем случае, если текст нельзя никак достать, то картинку вставляйте прямо в вопрос, а не ссылку на внешний ресурс.